# Wordpress - ACF: Disable repeater field in user profile for non admin users

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

In the user profile page I have a added a repeater `ACF` with 2 subfields (select and datepicker). I want this field to be disabled if the user is not administrator. So administrators can edit this field and the other users can only view it. Is that possible?

I have tried the solution found [here](https://www.role-editor.com/hide-disable-wordpress-user-profile-fields/) but it work only for simple fields and not `ACF`.

If it's not possible, how I can create a table and fetch the fields from the database to render them in user profile page?

Here is the code I used to disable normal fields:

```
/* Disables selected fields in (profile.php) */
function atroul_profile_fields_disable_js() {
?>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
      var fields_to_disable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'display_name'];
      for(i=0; i<fields_to_disable.length; i++) {
        if ( $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).length ) {
          $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
      }   
    });
  </script>
<?php
}

function atroul_profile_fields_disable() {
  global $pagenow;
  if ($pagenow!=='profile.php') 
  {
    return;
  }
  if (current_user_can('administrator')) 
  {
    return;
  }
  add_action( 'admin_footer', 'atroul_profile_fields_disable_js' );
  //add_action('admin_head','atroul_remove_personal_options');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'atroul_profile_fields_disable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the for loop with the below code

```
for(i=0; i<fields_to_disable.length; i++) {
        if ( $('tr[data-name="'+fields_to_disable[i]+'"]').length ) {
          $('tr[data-name="'+fields_to_disable[i]+'"] input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
          $('tr[data-name="'+fields_to_disable[i]+'"] select').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
      }
```

Comment: more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653984/wordpress-acf-disable-datepicker-field

Comment: plus I think In that case this answer is acceptable. Removing date pop up is different question.

Comment: No my requirement is to make it read only for non administrators